# UserDefaults and KVC: observeValueForKeyPath is not triggered when defaults change

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to observe any change to the *UserDefaults* in my iOS app. Since I want to monitor all the changes that occur even outside of the application (because they are changed from the iOS settings app), as far as I know I can't user *UserDefaults.didChangeNotification*:

> This notification isn't posted when changes are made outside the current process, or when ubiquitous defaults change. You can use key-value observing to register observers for specific keys of interest in order to be notified of all updates, regardless of whether changes are made within or outside the current process.

So I am adding an observer for each key-value pair in the user defaults:

```
for key in self.dictionary.keys { // The dictionary contains all the 
                                  // key-values that were registered
    userDefaults.addObserver(observer, forKeyPath: key, options: .new, context: nil)
}
```

The observer is a singleton object that is never deallocated, which implements this method:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print("Observe value for key path: \(keyPath ?? "Nil")")
    <do stuff>
}
```

But the problem is that this method is never triggered when I change the settings from the iOS settings app. I tried placing a breakpoint and the debugger never steps in this method, and the print function is never executed. What am I doing of wrong?

Comment: maybe it does not work because the app is in a background?

Comment: I am trying to get notifications even when the app is in background. Is this possible?